# The nonexistence of 8-transitive graphs

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, permutations, algebraic-graph-theory

In [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02579337) paper of Richard Weiss, he talks about the nonexistence of 8-transitive graphs, and mentions at the very beginning:

> We prove that the inequality $s \leq 7$ holds for finite $s$-transitive graphs assuming that the list of known $2$-transitive permutation groups is complete.

The list he means (I think) is the "list of finite $2$-transitive groups with a non-abelian minimal normal subgroup"
appearing in [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/blms/article-abstract/13/1/1/292329?redirectedFrom=PDF) by Peter Cameron.

Now my question is, since these papers are nearly forty years old, do we know now if this list is complete?
I tried to look it up myself but could not find anything. I am not super informed about the whole topic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, the completeness of the list of finite $2$-transitive groups follows from the classification of finite simple groups. It is generally thought to be unlikely that a proof will be found that does not use the classification.

Comment: I see, so this classification was not (fully) known at the time these papers were written?

Comment: I think the classification was known already at that point, he is just emphasing exactly in which way his result depends on the classification of finite simple groups. For example, if the CFSG was wrong, and there were other simple groups, but no new 2-transitive group, then it wouldn't affect Weiss' result.